# MVC Spring - loop with join left HQL query results

Tags: spring, templates

I have results from

```
Query query = session.createQuery("From Pool as p left join fetch p.poolQuestion as s");
```

query and i would like to display it on JSP.

I have loop:

```
<c:forEach items="${pools}" var="pool"> 

        <p>${pool.name}</p>

</c:forEach>
```

and I would like to display results from poolQuestion table (which is Join table). The value that i want to display is 'answer'.

How i can do it?

```
    <c:forEach items="${pools}" var="pool"> 
            <p>${pool.answer}</p>
            <p>${pool.name}</p>

    </c:forEach>
```

The above code doesn't works.

The error is:

```
  org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp at line 21

18:     <c:forEach items="${pools}" var="pool"> 
19:             
20:             <p>${pool.name}</p>
21:             <c:out value="${pool.poolQuestion.answer}"/>
22:             
23:     </c:forEach>
24:
```

The model is:

```
public List<Pool> getAll(){


        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();


        Query query = session.createQuery("From Pool as p left join fetch p.poolQuestions as s");


        return query.list();
```

The controller is:

```
List<Pool> pool = poolService.getAll();

        model.addAttribute("pools", pool);
```

And the View is:

```
<c:forEach items="${pools}" var="pool"> 

            <p>${pool.name}</p>
            <c:out value="${pool.answer}"/>

    </c:forEach>
```

PS. the ${pool.name} is displayed propertly

**

### OK, i got it, my code should looks like this:

**

```
<c:forEach items="${pools}" var="pool">

    <c:out value="${pool.name}"/>

    <c:forEach items="${pool.poolQuestions}" var="poolq">

        <c:out value="${poolq.answer}" />

    </c:forEach>



</c:forEach>
```

I neet to do one more forEach...

Comment: What does "doesn't works" (sic) look like?  Are there error messages or stack traces or some other hint?  What object do you add to the model map?  The Query?

Comment: The Error is from JSP - the loop doesn't find the variable

Comment: Show us the code which stored the result of the query in the request. If this code doesn't exist, then you have your answer: you need to make the pools available to the JSP, by putting them in a request attribute.

Answer (score 0):

trying to get the answer from the pool won't work, as the answer property is inside the question.

Your code should be

```
${pool.poolQuestion.answer}
```

And you should make sure to HTML-escape it, to make sure your HTML is valid and you can't have an XSS attack. use

```
<c:out value="${pool.poolQuestion.answer}"/>
```

Comment: it still doesn't work, nor ${pool.poolQuestion.answer} nor ${pool.s.answer}

Answer (score 0):

when I user HQL session.createQuery() method I had to fetch the data in the form of index and  not by calling the property direclty eg ${pool.name} ,${poolq.answer}

Instead use the index

```
<c:out value="${pool[0]}"/>
```

and so on.

any other suggestion will be appreciated.